# Simple Text popup using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to assign a mouse over pop-up (over an img tag) in JavaScript? I found some tutorials but they seem to use loads of code.  Using Jquery or any other framework? thx

Comment: `<img src="img.png" title="Mouseover text" />`?